# Excel Replace an index of characters with an index of corresponding words

Tags: excel

I'm attempting to replace an index of characters with corresponding words that are exclusive to those characters.
Example:

```
R = Red
G = Green
W = White
B = Black
U = Blue
```

I am aware this can be done with a series of IF statements, but I'd greatly prefer a more streamlined process, especially since I may be adding significantly more characters to be replaced. I should also add that the cell I am referencing to get the original character will only contain that character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place your little table in, say **E1** through **F5**.  Place the single character value in **A1** and in **B1** enter:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,E1:F5,2)
```

[image]

Comment: OP, if you add `FALSE` to the forth criterion of VLOOKUP the data does not need to be sorted: `=VLOOKUP(A1,E:F,2,FALSE)`

Comment: And based on Gary's work, you could use index with match thus: =index(F1:F5,match(A1,E1:E5,0)). A benefit is that the order of items does not have to be left to right, so the colors could be in column E and the letters in F...